# Construction of homogeneous space

Tags: matrices, smooth-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

Given a Hilbertspace $\mathcal{H}$ of dimension $n<\infty$ and all hermitian matricies $Symm(\mathcal{H})$. I'd guess that the set $M_{2,2} \subset Symm(\mathcal{H})$ of all matricies of rank 4 and with two positive and two negative eigenvalues is a manifold with real dimension $8n-16$.

Now I want to construct the set $M_{2,2}$ as a homogeneous space. To check the dimension. But I'm not sure which subgroup I should divied out of $Symm(\mathcal{H})$ to obtain $M_{2,2}$. Can someone help?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you say, but anyway: $M_{2,2}=U(n)/H $, where $H$ is the stabilizer of the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries 
$(1,1,-1,-1,0,\ldots )$. The question would be more appropriate on MSE.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So the group $U(n)$ hast to act transitively on $M_{2,2}$ by the action $(U,M) \mapsto UM$?

Comment: No, by $(U,M)\mapsto UMU^{-1}$ — this is just diagonalization of hermitian matrices.

Comment: But then the two matrices are unitary similar and have the same eigenvalues. But two matrices $M_1,M_2\in M_{2,2}$ don't have the same eigenvalues in general? Only the same signature.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. The group which acts transitively on $M_{2,2}$ is $GL(n)$, acting by $(A,M)\mapsto \bar{A}^TMA$.